# Why is "if [ -z "ls -l /non_existing_file 2> /dev/null" ] not true

Tags: shell, if-statement

I want to check if an external drive is still plugged in by checking /dev/disk/by-uuid/1234-5678.

However, I know that this could be done much easier with:

```
if ! [ -e "/non_existing_file" ]
   echo "File dont exists anymore"
fi
```

But I still want to know why the script in the Title dont work. Is it because of the exit code of ls?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `"ls -l /non_existing_file 2>/dev/null"` is not an empty string. `-z` tests for empty strings.

Comment: If you **ran** `ls` as a command and substituted its output, that would be different -- but you aren't doing that.

Comment: @rjs : Why can't you simply do a `if [ -e /dev/disk/by-uuid/1234-5678 ]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `ls -l /nonexisting` is a string that is not executed. This should work correctly if it is executed in a subshell.

Compare the example in the title:

```sh
if [[ -z "ls -l something.txt 2> /dev/null" ]]; then 
  echo "file does not exist"
fi
```

... with this version that returns as expected:

```sh
if [[ -z "$(ls -l something.txt 2> /dev/null)" ]]; then
  echo "file does not exist"
fi
```

Comment: Note the guidance in the *Answer Well-Asked Questions* section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) regarding questions that have "been asked and answered many times before".